# Dplyr reshape data from start and stop level to weekly level

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that contains user ID, subscription start and end date, and if available an activity date. Users can appear more than once if they have multiple activity dates. Below is a short toy example:

```
USER_ID      SUB_START     SUB_END      ACTIVITY_DATE
  0102       2018-01-02   2018-01-07          NA
  2190       2018-01-01   2018-01-06      2018-01-02
  2432       2018-01-03   2018-01-07      2018-01-03
  0121       2018-01-03   2018-01-04      2018-01-02
  0121       2018-01-02   2018-01-07      2018-01-04
```

What I would like to accomplish is group by week and then show the number of unique ID's that had an active subscription that week and the number of unique IDs that had at least 1 activity date that week. So the output for this toy data set would look like:

```
 WEEK    ACTIVE_COUNT    ACTIVITY_COUNT
2018-0         4               3
```

This example is simplified the time between the SUB_START and SUB_END dates can be much larger. I am trying to think about how to approach this problem. I need to create the WEEK column that contains every week from the smallest `format(SUB_START), "%y-%U")` to the largest `format(as.Date(SUB_END), "%Y-%U")`. Which I believe I can accomplish with something like `complete(WEEK = seq.Date(SUB_START, unit = "week"), SUB_END, by = "week"))`. However I am unsure about how I can then go through each week and count the number of unique ID's that were active during that week and count the number of unique active ID's who had at least one ACTIVITY_DATE within that week.

EDIT:
Using @TimTeaFan's framework I have gotten close with the following code:

```
dat %>% 
                  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ floor_date(as.Date(.x) - 1, "weeks") + 1)) %>% 
                  rowwise() %>% 
                  mutate(WEEK = list(seq(SUB_START,SUB_END, by = "+1 week"))) %>%
                  unnest(WEEK) %>% 
                  mutate(WEEK2 = format(WEEK, "%Y-%U")) %>% 
                  mutate(ENCOUNTER_WEEK = format(ACTIVITY_DATE, "%Y-%U")) %>%
                  group_by(WEEK2) %>% 
                  mutate(ACTIVE = ifelse(!is.na(ACTIVITY_DATE), ENCOUNTER_WEEK == WEEK2, NA)) %>% 
                  summarise(ACTIVE_COUNT = sum(!is.na(USER_ID)),
                            ACTIVITY_COUNT = sum(ACTIVE, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However this gives the total `ACTIVITY_COUNT` and not the unique number of ID's with an activity that week

EDIT2: Resolved Below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for (note that I changed your example data, since all start and end dates were in the same week).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat <- tribble(~USER_ID,      ~SUB_START,     ~SUB_END,      ~ACTIVITY_DATE,
               0102,       "2018-01-02",   "2018-01-07",          NA,
               2190,       "2018-01-01",   "2018-03-06",      "2018-01-02",
               2432,       "2018-01-03",   "2018-05-07",      "2018-01-03",
               0121,       "2018-01-03",   "2018-02-04",      "2018-01-02",
               0121,       "2018-01-02",   "2018-01-15",      "2018-01-04")

dat %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ floor_date(as.Date(.x) - 1, "weeks") + 1)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(WEEK = list(seq(SUB_START, SUB_END, by = "+1 week"))) %>%
  unnest(WEEK) %>% 
  mutate(WEEK2 = format(WEEK, "%Y-%U")) %>% 
  mutate(ENCOUNTER_WEEK = format(ACTIVITY_DATE, "%Y-%U")) %>%
  group_by(WEEK2, USER_ID) %>% 
  mutate(ACTIVE = ifelse(!is.na(ACTIVITY_DATE), ENCOUNTER_WEEK == WEEK2, NA)) %>% 
  summarise(ACTIVITY_COUNT = sum(ACTIVE, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  summarise(ACTIVE_COUNT = n(),
            ACTIVITY_COUNT = sum(ifelse(ACTIVITY_COUNT > 0, 1, 0)))

#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'WEEK2' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 19 x 3
#>    WEEK2   ACTIVE_COUNT ACTIVITY_COUNT
#>    <chr>          <int>          <dbl>
#>  1 2018-00            4              3
#>  2 2018-01            3              0
#>  3 2018-02            3              0
#>  4 2018-03            3              0
#>  5 2018-04            3              0
#>  6 2018-05            2              0
#>  7 2018-06            2              0
#>  8 2018-07            2              0
#>  9 2018-08            2              0
#> 10 2018-09            2              0
#> 11 2018-10            1              0
#> 12 2018-11            1              0
#> 13 2018-12            1              0
#> 14 2018-13            1              0
#> 15 2018-14            1              0
#> 16 2018-15            1              0
#> 17 2018-16            1              0
#> 18 2018-17            1              0
#> 19 2018-18            1              0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is an amazing start - thank you. `ACTIVE_COUNT` seems to be working correctly however for `ACTIVITY_COUNT` I am only looking for the number of unique ID's that had an activity that week. So for your new example data set the only week that would have any `ACTIVITY_COUNT` would be 2018-00 and it would be three since users `2190. 2432, 0121` all had an activity that week, sorry if my initial post was not clear.

Comment: I edited my answer. Shouldn't it be 4 user with an activity in the first week?

Comment: Three because I am looking for unique ID's and `0121` appears twice

Comment: I revised my answer again, I think, now it reflects your desired output.

Comment: Still not exactly what I am looking for, I have gotten closer using your framework, I will edit the question.

Comment: You are right, I misspecified `ACTIVE`, now I use your definition based on `ENCOUNTER_WEEK` and now it should work.